# CSRF cookie not set. Django 2.1.2

Tags: python, django, csrf

Учусь работать с Django 2.1.2
При попытке отправить POST, получаю на выходе такое:

> Forbidden (403) CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.CSRF cookie not set.

Views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.views.generic import View
from django.contrib import messages
from guess.forms import PostForm
# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    if request.method =='GET':
        return render(request, 'guessApp/index.html', {'name':'Some_name'})

class GuessBook(View):
    def get(self, request):
        form = PostForm()
        c = {'form':form}
        return render_to_response('guessApp/form.html', c)

    def post(self,request):
        form = PostForm(data = request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            messages.success(request, form.cleand_data['message'])
        else:
            message.error(request, 'Validation failed')
        c = {'form':form}
        return render_to_response('guessApp/form.html', c )
```

Forms:

```
from django import forms
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class PostForm(forms.Form):
    name=forms.CharField()
    message = forms.CharField()

    def clean_name(self):
        name=self.cleaned_data['name']
        if len(name) < 3:
            raise ValidationError('Name is too short. Try again.')
        return name
```

Forms.html:

```
{% extends "guessApp/base.html" %}

{% block content %}
  <div>
    <h2>Guest Book</h2>

    {% if messages %}
    <ul>
        {% for message in messages %}
        <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    {% endif %}

    <form action="{% url 'form' %}" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" >
    </form>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Я понятия не имею, почему не пропускает мой запрос.

Comment: «CSRF cookie not set» — у вас куки в браузере хоть включены? В другом браузере пробовали?

Comment: Куки включены. В Мозилле тоже не работает.

Comment: Проверьте `settings.py` на наличие `CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True`, если есть - удалите. Также проверьте наличие `django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware` в `MIDDLEWARE`, оно должно быть ДО остальных middleware, которые используются вьюхами.